# Divide entire column in excel (accounting) in 2 separate column (symbol + value)

Tags: excel, symbols, accounting

how to divide excel field with format accounting omitted, for example:
$ 220
€ 140
$ 220
€ 140
$ 220
€ 140
$ 220
€ 140
etc...etc...
So, from one field-column A, to get 2 column A (for accounting symbol) and B (for value)?

Comment: Do you actually have the currency value in the cell, or are you saving "220" in the cell and then using the Accounting format?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

First column:

[image]

Second column:

[image]

The first extracts a char from the beggining, and the second removes the first two displaying 100 chars ahead. You can convert the second column to number by wrapping the formula in a value().

**Update:**

If you know that will be a space between the two you can use this formulas instead and parse a more than one char accounting symbol:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1))

=MID(A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1;100)
```

Comment: It depends -- if the value is saved in the cell as 220, but he is using the Accounting format, Left(A1,1) will return "2", and not "$".  At least that's the behavior in Excel 2003.